# mate-panel: Finding auto-hide in dconf editor

Tags: panel, mate, dconf, autohide

Most parameters in the mate-panel properties directly relate in the dconf editor to

```
/org/mate/panel/toplevels/top/    resp. /bottom/
```

[image]

For example, changing the size gives instant feedback on either side.

**What I cannot find is a matching dconf-value for AutoHide.** Nowhere to be found.

It *is* changeable by command line. (And doing so has the desired effect.) - Why does dconf editor not show it?

```
$> dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/auto-hide true
$> dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/auto-hide false
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu, MATE and dconf editor versions? This appears to be a bug in one of the latter

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a problem with your Ubuntu version, your MATE installation, or your Dconf Editor. This is MATE 1.16.0 on Ubuntu 16.10, with Dconf Editor 3.20.3.

[image]

For me, the `auto-hide` key is present in `dconf-editor`.